# what is the difference between 现场 and 地点?

Tags: difference

Do both of them mean "location" or "site", or is there something that sets them apart? Thank you in advance!

Comment: iciba  
现场 释义相关词条
locale scene theater  。。。 
地点 释义相关词条
locus place site situs spot 。。。
also many examples showing difference， also quotes 百科 for both

Comment: Ah, I'll remember to check out iciba next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

地点 = location, while 现场 = being present at a location

地点 normally describes a precise location.

现场 describes the fact that some one is in a place. That place can be a precise location or an area.

For example

请告诉我地点。
Please tell me the location.

我在现场，请告诉我具体地点。
I am here, please tell me the exact location.

Comment: 现场 = scene?  Being present at a location sounds more like 现在的位置, thou it basically means the same

Comment: This response was great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

现场 scene eg. crime scene 犯罪现场
地点 location or address

Comment: Could you add some more examples, besides crime scene?

Answer (score 3):

现场 is a 地点, more specifically, it's a specific 地点. You can understand it in this way: think 地点 as the word "location" or "site" or "scene", in English, you normally wouldn't just say "site" or "location", you have to define it with an article, so it would be come "the location/site" or "a location/site". Now, you could think 现场 as "the site/scene". See the transition here?

That's way you can use 地点 in a unspecific context, but you can only use 现场 in a more specific context. For example 犯罪现场, means "crime scene", not necessarily "THE crime scene", but still you need to define 现场 with crime. Or the specification may be implicit in the context. For example "I arrived at 现场(the site)" here 现场 is specific to whatever place the speaker is talking about.

All this is because of the character 现 which means present, now, current, which are little bit similar to the function of "the".

Answer (score 3):

地点 is a place where something is or could be located.
现场 is the place where an action or event occurs.

Comment: This is the right distinction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use the two, others' explanations are correct, and here are some tips to add to the picture. 地點 is a somewhat formal word that is used nearly interchangeably with most other words for "place," though it is rarely used in casual conversation. You'll typically encounter it in literature and news, that is, written mediums. It sounds very "dictionary" in tone: "某個地點" is a common example you'll see. Encyclopedic, scientific sounding writing will prefer 地點 over some of the "place" alternatives for its formality.

現場 is not very related in meaning as others have made clear. It requires some context around it usually, as you'll see an example given was not just any scene but a "crime scene." Using 現場 without some matching context that specifies the "scene" it's referring to is uncommon. A great word to know for 現場 is 現場直播. Literally has a "live stream/on the air" kind of meaning but also is used as slang for PDA (public display of affection). I find this makes this word hard to forget.